# Can we build a network switch chip by ourself?

Tags: networking, switch

Looks it it simple enough - just forward package to other port. I am wondering if is possible to build it on some common ARM SOC. Didn't need care about the speed or advance feature.

Comment: Much too broad and off topic here. Consider [electronics.SE] but please check their scope first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid its not nearly so simple. First off, you would need to fully implement [802.3](http://www.ieee802.org/3/) to the desired level, in order to work with other network equipment, even workstation nics. If you are using an existing OSes network stack, you don't need to implement it yourself. perhaps somthing like this will work: http://www.pica8.com/open-switching/open-switching-overview.php

More importantly, commercial switches operate in hardware using [Application Specific Integrated circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit), which process data at much higher rates than software can support, and are arranged for multiple streams in parallel, to reduce the overall load on the switch. A High capacity backplane and appropriately situated IO buffers are a must.

The job will take some hardware engineering at a minimum, and unless you really want to spend a lot of time on it, the result would not really be worth using. if you just want to see if you can though, by all means, try it and let us know how it works out.